# Monitoring MySQL Rollback Segments

Tags: linux, mysql, innodb, rollback

I recently discovered the default open transaction ceiling of 1024 in MySQL. I have since increased the limit using innodb_extra_rsegments. However, I would like to keep my eye on this moving forward. My MySQL version is 5.1.48. Is there a way to monitor the open transactions at a point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` will give insight as to how far back your history list is, how many transactions are pending/active and other super useful diagnostics.

[You can get the full rundown here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-monitors.html)

Also, this has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172127/can-i-retrieve-pending-queries-during-an-innodb-transaction